# Android Alarm with user defined playlist as sound and time

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, alarm

I'm creating an Alarm based Android app where **I should pass an custom playlist as alarm sound** when alarm start user have to set how much time its gonna run and that playlist sounds run as alarm started and I don't have any idea how to create it I just want an logic no code.
App reference Alarm clock HD
https://play.google.com/store/search?q=alarm%20clock%20hd

Answer (score 0):

```
public class serv extends Service{

    MediaPlayer mp;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    public void onCreate()
    {   
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.b);
        mp.setLooping(false);
    }
    public void onDestroy()
    {       
        mp.stop();
    }
    public void onStart(Intent intent,int startid){

        Log.d(tag, "On start");
        mp.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, your answer led me towards the right solution, your method is not 100 percent correct, but I got the idea after seeing your answer, So I'll update it later with the correct solution.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.